# Ошибка при docker run

Tags: nginx, docker

Запускаю такую команду:

```
docker run --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web -v "${PWD}:/usr/share/nginx/html" nginx
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /usr/share/nginx/html.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

PWD (Текущая папка в которой я нахожусь) у меня `C:\Users\egork\IdeaProjects\plan\test`.

Если что у меня windows 10 и я работаю в poweshell 7.

Comment: Похоже на это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540721

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо!